# Unable to resize pieChart smaller react native gifted charts

Tags: react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

I have a card with a lineChart and a pieChart added to it. I need to make the pieChart smaller, and I have already done some research, but I keep getting the same answer: to use the innerRadius property.
[This is how it is right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKhvn.png)

this is how i would like the pieChart to be:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjvZM.png)

Comment: `react-native-gifted-chat`? Are you confused with `react-native-chart-kit`?

Comment: Hi @DinhNguyen He wanted to tag `react-native-gifted-charts` but the tag is not available yet, so he might have accidentally tagged `react-native-gifted-chat`

Answer (score 1):

To make the Pie chart smaller, use the `radius` property. `innerRadius` is used to set the radius of the inner circle for donut charts.
[image: radius Pie chart]

Comment: After spending some time searching, unfortunately I could not find in the documentation how to modify the element size. However, this experience could be considered as an improvement opportunity for the documentation.

Best regards and thank you very much! The solution you provided worked perfectly.